# Is it considered a bad practice to store a list of ids in a sql table column?

Tags: sql, database-design

I am creating an application with a game lobby and players, of which there can be a varying number. I was thinking of creating a table RaceDetails with having a column named Players with a list of User IDs. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: **YES! That's a horribly bad practice!** In a relational database, if you need to store multiple things - you need a **relation** - e.g. a separate table to hold these values, using a foreign key reference to link those to the "main" entity in question

Comment: It is always a bad idea to store any list in any single column *because it is a violation of first normal form*.  You store lists in the multiple associated rows of a child table, never packed into a column of a single row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: Thanks for the comments - so I should create a seaprate table that holds the relation of players in a game lobby?